# Meteor: Passing array parameter to template

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to pass an array to another template in Meteor.
Why? Because I would like to create a small template for each Bootstrap element, allowing me to reuse components much more easily.

> {{> dropdown id="dropdown1" textDropdown="My dropdown!" listItems=["item1", "item2"] }}

This does not seem to work unfortunately.

Any clue? Does what I'm doing even make sense? I'm new to Meteor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spacebars is currently pretty limited in what it can accept - you'll need to add a helper to accomplish this:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  listItems: ['item1', 'item2']
});
```

And them modify your template:

```
{{> dropdown id="dropdown1" textDropdown="My dropdown!" listItems="{{listItems}}"}}
```

Make sure to update `myTemplate` to the parent template's name.

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty inconvenient.. thanks for the info David.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add a helper which returns the whole context for the dropdown (id, listItems, and textDropdown) as a single object. That may or may not be more convenient depending on your situation.

Comment: I think the main issue at this point is that I can't reuse the template if I need to use the helper, so it's completely missing the point.

Comment: @DavidWeldon How come you can do `listItems="{{listItems}}"`? It just doesnt work for me, it passes that string literally instead.

Comment: That's valid spacebars syntax. I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for you unless you are using a preprocessor of some kind. Consider posting this as a new question so you can share more details.

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC, probably much too late to be useful, but `listItems="{{listItems}}"` is indeed invalid syntax. To achieve what you're trying to do, having defined `listItems` as a helper in your JS file, you must pass `listItems=listItems`. No more double curly bracket notation is allowed once already inside a Spacebars expression.

Comment: @cneuro then the answer should be corrected. Thanks btw.